# How to invoke another function using a parameter fetched JSON result of API call from AJAX

Tags: ajax, reactjs, spfx

I Have to get ParentId from this function using JSON result and then invoke another function given below after this function:

```
public fetchLibraryDatafromSharePointList(clientID:string) {
  debugger;
  const reactHandler = this;
  jquery.ajax({  
    url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MSAs')/items?$filter=ClientID eq '${clientID}'&$orderby=Modified desc`,
    type: "GET",  
    headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},  
    success: function(resultData2) {
reactHandler.setState({  
        items: resultData2.d.results  
      });  
    },  
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
    }  
});  
}
```

Below is the function which has to be invoked on the success of above API and the parameter is coming in the JSON result of the previous call made:-

SetState is done by reactHandler variable

```
public fetchDatafromSharePointList(ParentID) {
 debugger;
  const reactHandler = this;
  jquery.ajax({ 
url:`${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MSASummaries')/items? 
    $filter=Parent eq ${ParentID}$top=1&$orderby=Modified desc`,  
        type: "GET",  
        headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},  
        success: function(resultData) {  
          /*resultData.d.results;*/  
           reactHandler.setState({  
            items: resultData.d.results  
          });  
        },  
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
        }  
    });  
    }
```

Comment: I think you should edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke another function in the success response of `fetchLibraryDatafromSharePointList(clientID:string)` after updating state. i.e:

```
reactHandler.setState({  
    items: resultData2.d.results  
  }, ()=>{
     fetchDatafromSharePointList(your_parent_id_goes_here);
  });
```